# Hashmap values of existing keys getting overwritten upon using put to store a new key-value pair. how to prevent it?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();//arraylist as value

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            al.add(i + j);
        }
        System.out.println(al);
        System.out.println(j);//key value
        map.put(j, al);
        System.out.println(map);
        al.clear();
    }
```

Why does the last value arraylist get overwritten on all keys? How to avoid over writing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();//arraylist as value
```

inside the loop.

You want to create the `ArrayList` for each object, not only one for all.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        al.add(i + j);
    }
    System.out.println(al);
    System.out.println(j);//key value
    map.put(j, al);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Comment: No. It clears the array, but you use the same array over and over. Using "put" saves the arraylist reference, not a copy, so changing the arraylist after putting it actually changes the map value.

Comment: oh fine! Thanks for clearing the doubt.. Now my code works fine.

Comment: OMG! <<Using "put" saves the arraylist reference, not a copy>> WORDS OF GOLD. that was crucial. thanks @BobTheBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse the old `ArrayList` by just clearing it, you need to create a new one every time:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        al.add(i + j);
    }
    System.out.println(al);
    System.out.println(j);//key value
    map.put(j, al);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

The reason is that the `HashMap` will point all entries to the same `ArrayList` which will be overwritten each run.