# Hashmap entry overwrites previous entry despite different key

Tags: java, hashmap, tuples

I'm running into issues with a Hashmap in my program overwriting the value of previous Hashmap entries despeinte the two entries having different keys.

```
    public void drawTheNumbers() {
    final int NO_WIN = 0;
    int playerOneTicketWinning = 0;
    Tuple numberTransporter = new Tuple (0,0);
    for(Journal entry : theJournal) {
        playerOneTicketWinning = entry.getWinning();
        if (winningsPerPlayer.containsKey(entry.getPerson())) {
            numberTransporter.playerTotalWinnings = numberTransporter.playerTotalWinnings + playerOneTicketWinning;
            numberTransporter.playerSimilarities = numberTransporter.playerSimilarities + entry.getSimilarities();

            winningsPerPlayer.put(entry.getPerson(), numberTransporter );
        }else {
            numberTransporter.playerTotalWinnings = playerOneTicketWinning;
            numberTransporter.playerSimilarities = entry.getSimilarities();
            winningsPerPlayer.put(entry.getPerson(), numberTransporter);
        }   
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Tuple> player: winningsPerPlayer.entrySet()) {
        int temp1 = numberTransporter.getplayerTotalWinnings();
        int temp2 = NO_WIN;
        if (temp1 == temp2) {
            noWinMessage (player.getKey());
        }else {
            playerWinningsMessage(player.getKey(), numberTransporter);
        }
    }
}
```

When this loop is run the second time around it will overwrite the values of playerTotalWinnings and playerSimilarities in the method above, but also in the previously entry in the Hashmap created by winningsPerPlayer.put

The key is the name of the player entered by the user when running the program. Multiple users can run the program within the same session.

Comment: If it is run by multiple users per session you should consider to add some logging, in order to see for which keys values are replaced.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522542/hashmap-values-of-existing-keys-getting-overwritten-upon-using-put-to-store-a-ne for similar problem. You need to retrieve Tuple from map for given key and insert new one if it is missing.

Comment: @JoopEggen entry.getPerson() has nothing to do with the issue. It is numberTransporter which is being shared and overwritten with results.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski thanks, did not read till the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key might be different. But the value is not -_-°

You need to create a new Tuple inside the loop, instead of constantly modifying the one and only you created before the loop.

Generally something like a Tuple should not need to be modified after its creation, it should be created with the two values it will contain and never changed from that. So it should be made immutable, with final values, so that you avoid that kind of silly mistakes.